# cache:false in ajax call attach a value with URl

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, caching, backbone.js

If I set AJAX cache to false using:

> $.ajaxSetup ({
>        cache: false    });

Then my resulting AJAX URL has the characters &_=1381901096821 added to the end so that the browser (especially IE) sees it as a new page request.

The resulting call is:
eg
=1381901096821">http://MyServer/authcheck?=1381901096821

But I don't want that value attached with the URL. Is there any way to remove it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is probably the most reliable way to prevent browser caching on AJAX requests. Why do you want to remove it?

Comment: Its an API call. So extra parameters with URL returning error. I prefer to avoid this value, than back-end code edit

Comment: do you have caching problem? why do you wan to set `cache: false`?

Answer (score 1):

You can set cache to true:

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: true
});
```

Then manually add no-cache headers:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function (xhr)
    {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    },
});
```

Comment: That is not working. when I call the url in IE9 its showing "pending" state. So I was trying it by clearing the ajax cache. But still it shows pending state